# Trying to insert python datetime into SQL DATE

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Trying to insert python datetime into SQL DATE but an error keeps appearing saying OperationalError: near "02": syntax error

```
import  sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect("Date_time3.db")
print("Database Opened successfully")
conn.execute("""
CREATE TABLE ADMIN(
EXPIRE DATETIME PRIMARY KEY
)
""")
```

This is my database^

```
import datetime 
import pytz
import  sqlite3

today = datetime.datetime.now()
date_time = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

conn=sqlite3.connect("Date_time3.db")
print("Database Opened successfully")

conn.execute("INSERT INTO ADMIN(EXPIRE) VALUES " +date_time);



conn.commit()
print ("Records inserted successfully")
conn.close()
"""
###Output###
#Database Opened successfully
#Records inserted successfully
#"""
print ("Table ADMIN created successfully")
"""
####Output###
Database Opened successfully
Table ADMIN created successfully
"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO ADMIN(EXPIRE) VALUES " +date_time);
```

to

```
conn.execute('INSERT INTO ADMIN(EXPIRE) VALUES (?)', [date_time]);
```

As you are running SQL commands, they work differently from Python. So you cannot use `+` operators. You need to use placeholders like `(?)`

Comment: that didnt work my error that im getting now is:  ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 20 supplied.

Comment: It should be `conn.execute('INSERT INTO ADMIN(EXPIRE) VALUES (?)', [date_time])`.

Comment: thanks you so much that worked ive been struggling for so long

Comment: @acw1668 : Edited. However, there is only one date passed in. How is it a list?

Comment: The second argument of `execute()` must be either tuple or list even there is only one value.